# List of animationID in beginAnimations method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I there any specific list for animationID in `+ (void)beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context` method ?
for example I see this code :

```
[UIView beginAnimations : @"Display notif" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:FALSE];

    CGRect frame = paperCurl.frame;
    frame.size.height -= 40;
    frame.origin.y += 40;
    paperCurl.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hello.... we cant read your mind!!! "has a kind of different animation"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This key is not any pre-defined standard keys.These keys just a user-defined names to refer this animation for future use.[Check this link for reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html)

Comment: Link isn't valid anymore